# Unpermitted parameters for form_with(:url) in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, strong-parameters

I have:

```
<%= form_with url: retrieve_videos_path, local: true do |form| %>
   # some form stuff
   <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And when I submit it, logs signal about unpermitted parameters: `Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :authenticity_token, :commit`

I guess, in forms for models these parameters are permitted by the 'require' method like:

```
params.require(:model).permit(:params_stuff)
```

But how to make the same for urls?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Well, I think it should be considered as warning message rather than error. Maybe it can cause a security weakness. For some time I've been ignoring these messages and now I would like to know it for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `:url` Rails doesn't have anything to nest the forms params *inside*.  But we can provide that with the `:scope` option.

```
<%= form_with url: retrieve_videos_path, scope: :videos, local: true do |form| %>
   # some form stuff
   <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller:

```rb
def video_params
  params.require(:videos).permit(:params_stuff)
end
```

This effectively makes it so this form's params are nested inside a `videos` key.  Once they're nested you can use the usual require..permit flow you're used to.  You can avoid the need to do this by not using `:url` (except for external forms) and instead using the `:model` option with a model instance.  Either way should avoid the logged warning.